# Importing a csv file yields weird first character

Tags: import, data, csv-format

Whenever I import a CSV file, I get this weird character at the beginning of the file ,I am not sure why. How can I avoid this?
[image]

Comment: I have a guess, but I need a couple of pieces of information, first. First, what version are you using? Second, what does `FullForm@data9k[[1]]` return? Lastly, what does `PacletFind["SVTools"]` return?

Comment: @Indeterminate like rcollyerI have a guess. I think if it is in all your files that I could be the BOM.

Comment: @Indeterminate please see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark] see table. If you concur then how to solve? I believe you need to indicate the Character Encoding in your Import.

Comment: @Indeterminate Please try `Import["yourfilenamehere", "CSV" , CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"]`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Import["yourfilenamehere", "CSV", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"]
```